# How to customize Catia

Tags: security, authorization, catia

How customizable Catia is? Can you customize Catia's screens? Workflow?

I want to intercept user actions in Catia and authorize them by calling an external authorization service.

If a user is trying to view certain documents or screens etc - I want to each time authorize his actions using an external service. My service is ready - but I am trying to figure out if I can customize Catia to make such an external webservice call every time a user tries to do something in Catia.

Answer (score 0):

using CAA such things are possible to do

or more interesting approach, you can create custom environment where replacing standard catia icons with custom scripts which will be invoked from those shortcuts, in extreme case will lead to use of CAA again

otherwise you can have Catia on cloud so you have a step between user and Catia, but then you can count with lack of feedback issues

but CAA should be right choice